# How to hide an element if span is empty and check non-stop

Tags: php, jquery, html

Check below. The span, price amount final does change if 1 of the frame options has been selected. The problem here is if nothing is selected, the price amount final will stay 0,00 and it is now possible to add that to the cart. How can I manage to hide the button if option is not selected and if selected show and when unselected hide again.

```
//OPTIONT TO SELECT
<span class="label">Frame €25,00</span>
<span class="label">Frame €50,00</span>

//CHANGES PRICE ON SELECTED ITEM
<span class="price amount final">€0,00</span>

<button type="submit" class="add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart>Add to cart</button>


//I found this but it will not work. This code below needs to be executed non-stop as they can unselect.
if(.price.amount.final <= €0,00)
{
$(".add_to_cart_button").hide();
}else{
$(".add_to_cart_button").show();
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code that changes the price? That might be a good place to toggle the button on if the price is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button by default since the initial price is 0.00.

```
$('.add_to_cart_button').hide();
```

Use [jquery change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) to detect if "price amount final" has changed (make sure to change to an input because it won't work on span elements since it checks for val not the text)

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

or you can simply trigger a simple custom function on an event and check the span text value

```
function checkvalue(){
  if ( $('.final') == '0' ){
    log('equals 0');
  }
}
```